# How to grouping and apply function in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables like below.

I would like to subtract all `customers` who has  `product = A`

```
product  customer
A        A
B        A
C        B
B        B
A        C
B        C
.        .
.        .
.        .
```

Therefore my desired result is like below

```
product  customer
A        A
B        A
A        C
B        C
```

grouping by `customer`and then subtract...

But I am novice and I didn't come up with.

If someone has any opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think "subtract" is the right word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also try using `COUNT` as an analytic function here, with conditional aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN product = 'A' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY customer) AS a_cnt
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT product, customer
FROM cte
WHERE a_cnt > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean "return" not "subtract".  You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.customer = t.customer and t2.product = 'A'
             );
```

For best performance, you want an index on `(customer, product)`.  With such an index, this is probably the fastest approach.

Comment: Thank you for good use of `exist` !, I have described huge table and I would like to `extract` like result table. is this code reproductive? Thanks